# WPF: Constantly loading font file `ttf` e.g. `arial.ttf`

Tags: wpf, performance, fonts

I have a WPF application that updates a lot of text. I noticed using SysInternals `procmon.exe` that this constantly loads the font file e.g.

[image]

Why is this? It seems rather inefficient.

Comment: Yeah, you don't want to look behind the wpf curtain, that can be scary.  WPF uses a dedicated process to act as a cache for fonts.  Use Task Manager, Process tab, show processes for all users.  Verify that PresentationFontCache.exe is running.  Every cache needs to check if an update is required, probably that.  Don't worry about it too much, the file system cache forgives many sins.

Comment: I'm not sure whether WPF caches the _entire_ set of glyphs when the font is first requested; it might defer loading the individual glyphs (or at least less common glyphs) until you actually try to render them, access their metrics, etc.  IIRC, the cache stores _rasterized_ glyphs, which suggests that it may need to go back to the file if you later decide to display text at a significantly different size, in a different weight or style, etc.  As Hans says, I wouldn't about it.

Comment: Yeah, I have looked behind the curtain and I am still shaking ;) The problem is that this is not the PresentationFontCache.exe that is loading these, it is the WPF application itself and it happens A LOT.

Comment: We are not changing font size, font or anything. Just updating the same text field quite often. Problem is we have seen some very weird LONG hangs of the WPF app, and perhaps this was related to that.

Comment: I've seen the same thing, and this is the first post I have found about it.  The funny thing is that it happens only some times.  For a clock control, it will hit the font file for every update.  For other controls, it isn't hit at all.  On other controls, the font file will be hit every time a tooltip is displayed, but this doesn't happen on other controls.